# Which header do you set to prevent Outlook from forwarding an email (literally)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I've been tasked with creating a script to send announcement emails to clients using outlook to read their emails and they must not be able to forward them. Is there a header we can set to prevent forwarding that outlook recognizes?

This is a business requirement that has nothing to do with the actual security of the information in the email. What is required is that pressing the forward button in outlook will not work so our clients do not accidentally send forwards and are made aware it is intended that they do not forward the email.

Comment: Why bother?  What happens if the client is not using Outlook?   What about circumventing a block by composing a new email and copy'n'paste the "restricted" content?  You need to contact the IMF people for a device that destroys itself after the message is delivered.

Comment: It part of the business requirements for the application I am building. Our clients are employees who are required to use outlook for, "security reasons". The actual security of the information is not important, just that outlook will not forward it.

Comment: @random Sorry for the confusion I was trying to ask (literally) which header to set. Am I asking this in the right place? Could you please un-tag the questions as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, but does the linked question not address that you can't prevent forwards?

Comment: @random I am not concerned with actually preventing forwards. The email client outlook has a proprietary header they use for triggering a feature that prevents users from hitting the forward button. I require assistance finding out what proprietary header to include in the emails that my application sends to trigger this feature in this specific email client that supports it.

Comment: This feature of MS Exchange is called ([IRM](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Send-an-e-mail-message-with-restricted-permission-by-using-IRM-9026a694-889c-4f98-9889-7a96959886c7)) and it does not work with Internet e-mail.  You will have to use a program that communicates with Exchange, such as MS Outlook, to use this feature.  It also has to be enabled and configured by the system administrator.  Therefore, this question has no answer.